# How to read objects from REST API using python?

Tags: python, api, rest, server, raspberry-pi2

Can anybody have an idea about how to incorporate data from REST API on the RPi which is scripted in Python? Is there any way to send some commands to the RPi from the remote server? Any help towards it would be appreciated.

Comment: This is far too vague. If it's a REST API, then by definition you can query it by HTTP. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Actually I am not from programming background. But, I want to know whether the server/ cloud where REST API is running, be able to send any command to my RPi? You can think of as Can Global server send any command to the various users? If it does, then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keeping the answer to the scope of the question. Rest api can be accessed using `http` requests. the python standard library has a http client library and also there are a many libraries out [there](http://pypi.python.org) which provide features of a `http client`, i personally like [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

so basically install `requests` and then.

```
r = requests.get(url)

data = r.json() # as its a rest api you can directly access the json object 

print(data)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. As it seems, the code is for reading from the REST API. Can it be vice versa like  could REST API send the object to my Raspberry Pi (python)?

Comment: yeah `request.post` method can be used for that but please first i would recommend doing some reading on `http` and `rest`. Also accept the answer if you feel it answer's your question :-)

Comment: It somewhat answer my question but not fully. As of now I am able to read with `requests.get(url)`. I can even `post` data on to the URL. But, if I want to send commands from URL to my host machine, how can it be done?

Comment: answering from what i could understand , you can use `rpc` and one of the easy way to use `rpc` is to use `json` as the transport , you can get info about it. [here](http://json-rpc.org/)

Answer (score 1):

RPi is using rest API, so u can use urllib in python.

```
http://<ip of raspi>:3000/<pin>
```

[source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=81277)

example:

```
    from urllib.request import Request, urlopen   
    q = Request(url_with_get_parameters)
    q.add_header('some_header_info', 'value' )
    q.add_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
    response = urlopen(q).read()
```